# How to copy files between windows 7 computers using username and password?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking

I want to copy files from a windows PC (e.g. 1.2.3.4) to another windows PC. I am able to log in to the windows machine I want to copy files from using username and password (via `remote desktop`).

On the net I found [robocopy](http://klyavlin.wordpress.com/2012/09/19/robocopy-network-usernamepassword/), which uses `[net use][2]` to make the connection, or whatever (not clear on the purpose of `net use`). On the remote machine I want to copy files from I created a shared folder with network path "\alex\Data", and so I tried to use `net use` in the following way:

```
net use m: \\alex\Data password /user:alex
net use m: \\1.2.3.4\alex\Data password /user:alex
```

But in both cases no network path is being found:

```
System Error 53 Has Occurred. 

The network path was not found.
```

According to the documentation given, I seem to use `net use` correctly. So how can I fix the error I am getting?

Or maybe there is another (preferrrably simpler) way to copy files from one windows PC to another, using username and password to log in?

Comment: you can share files from one computer and copy files using another computer using user name and password

Comment: @Ayodhya: Great you summarized my question. However I would appreciate if you could explain HOW I could do that...

Comment: are you connected to a lan ?

Comment: @Ayodhya: Yes, both computers are connected to a LAN.

Answer (score 0):

**Right Click on the folder** (which you want to copy from one PC to another PC ) **> Properties > Advanced Sharing > Share the folder**

login to other computer go to **Network** here it will show your first computer Just double click it will ask for **user name and password** of first computer Just give it and open. It will show shared files and you can copy.

Comment: I already shared the folder on the remote computer I want to share, but this folder does not show up in 'Network' in the 'Windows-Explorer'.

Comment: @Alex you computer is not there in network or only folder is not showing.

Comment: I am not sure - do not know the computer's name. Only sure the folder name is not listed under 'Network'.

Comment: @Alex please confirm the computer's name because it will not show any folder under Network. Shows list of computers connected find you computer > open then it will show folder name

Comment: Then I stronly believe the computer's name is also not listed under 'Network'.

Comment: @Alex well. it may be due to public network I suggest you to choose the network as **Home Network** in remote computer. you can see this link http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows7/why-are-computers-missing-from-the-network-map

Comment: Is there really no other way to simply copy files from one windows 7 computer to another? I have been looking and trying for hours, while on Linux you get this done in seconds!!!